# Binding custom object consisting of different List<T> to a TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I want to bind the object of my Node class to a treeview.

Node Class

```
public class Node
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public List<Node> Child { get; set; }
        public List<NodeAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
        public bool IsLeafNode { get; set; }
        public bool HasAttributes { get; set; }
    }
```

NodeAttribute

```
public class NodeAttribute
    {
        public string Attribute { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I am able to dislplay Child using HierarchicalDataTemplate but not the Attributes.

```
<TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding Child}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Child}" DataType="{x:Type tvcc:Node}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

I want to style Child and attributes differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CompositeCollection to combine both Child and Attributes and bind them to the  HierarchicalDataTemplate's ItemsSource

I prepared a sample for you

Added a CompositeCollection ChildAndAttributes in Node class

```
public class Node
{
    public Node()
    {
        Child = new List<Node>();
        Attributes = new List<NodeAttribute>();
    }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Child { get; set; }
    public List<NodeAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public bool IsLeafNode { get; set; }
    public bool HasAttributes { get; set; }

    CompositeCollection comp;
    public CompositeCollection ChildAndAttributes
    {
        get
        {
            if (comp == null)
            {
                comp = new CompositeCollection();
                comp.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Child });
                comp.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Attributes });
            }
            return comp;
        }
    }
}
```

you can adjust the composite collection to have attributes first if needed, just change the order of adding to collection

XAML

```xml
    <TreeView Name="tv">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <!--created seperate tempates for Node and NodeAttribute-->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tvcc:Node}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                           Foreground="Navy" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tvcc:NodeAttribute}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribute}"
                           Foreground="Crimson" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <!--moved your original template to Item Template or tree-->
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <!--binded ChildAndAttributes to ItemsSource-->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildAndAttributes}">
                <!--this will pick up the data template for respective element-->
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <!--below is sample data-->
        <tvcc:Node Text="hello">
            <tvcc:Node.Attributes>
                <tvcc:NodeAttribute Attribute="attribute child" />
            </tvcc:Node.Attributes>
            <tvcc:Node.Child>
                <tvcc:Node Text="hello child">
                    <tvcc:Node.Attributes>
                        <tvcc:NodeAttribute Attribute="attribute child 1" />
                    </tvcc:Node.Attributes>
                </tvcc:Node>
            </tvcc:Node.Child>
        </tvcc:Node>
        <tvcc:Node Text="hello2">
            <tvcc:Node.Attributes>
                <tvcc:NodeAttribute Attribute="attribute child 2" />
            </tvcc:Node.Attributes>
            <tvcc:Node.Child>
                <tvcc:Node Text="hello child 2">
                    <tvcc:Node.Attributes>
                        <tvcc:NodeAttribute Attribute="attribute child 2" />
                    </tvcc:Node.Attributes>
                </tvcc:Node>
            </tvcc:Node.Child>
        </tvcc:Node>
    </TreeView>
```

you can modify the data templates as per your needs

**Alternative approach**

You can also modify your existing template to achieve similar without using CompositCollections

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Child}"
                            DataType="{x:Type tvcc:Node}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                    Foreground="Navy" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Attribute}"
                                Foreground="Crimson" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You can try both and choose what is best suited for your needs

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use CompositeCollection to solve your problem.

Here is the converter which converts your node to composite collection

```
public class CompositeNodeConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var node = value as Node;

            CompositeCollection collection = new CompositeCollection();
            CollectionContainer container = new CollectionContainer();
            container.Collection = node.Child;
            collection.Add(container);

            container = new CollectionContainer();
            container.Collection = node.Attributes;

            collection.Add(container);

            return collection;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and then you can bind this in your xaml as:

```
  <TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding NodeCollection}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <controls:CompositeNodeConverter x:Key="CompositeNodeConverter"></controls:CompositeNodeConverter>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CompositeNodeConverter}}" DataType="{x:Type controls:Node}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:NodeAttribute}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```